# Auto complete input date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I auto-complete an input date using JavaScript?
Like for example I input 5/2 it'll automatically be 20190502

```
function dateManagement(dateValue) {

  var inputs = dateValue.split('/');

  var month = (inputs[0].length == 1) ? '0' + inputs[0] : inputs[0];
  var date = (inputs[1].length == 1) ? '0' + inputs[1] : inputs[1];

  return new Date().getFullYear() + '' + month + '' + date;
}


    function setupLevel1ItemDateManagementEditFunction(dateValue){
        addLoadEvent(initLevel1ItemDateManagementEditFunction(dateValue));
    }


    function initLevel1ItemDateManagementEditFunction(dateValue){
       return function(){
          var dateVal = disp.getElement(dateValue);
          addEventHandler(dateVal ,"onkeydown", function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == KEY_ENTER){
           var input = disp.get(dateValue);
           var edited = "";
            try{
               edited = dateManagement(dateValue);
            } catch(e){
               console.log(e);
            }

            if(edited != "" && edited !=null){
               disp.set(dateValue, edited);
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
    return true;

     };

}
```

i have tried reading a lot of threads and forums and i still dont get it.

i am completely new to coding so pls bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bad approach to set a date. But if you really needs to do this, you can use following function.

```
function getFullDate(yourInputText) {

  var inputs = yourInputText.split('/');

  var month = (inputs[0].length == 1) ? '0' + inputs[0] : inputs[0];
  var date = (inputs[1].length == 1) ? '0' + inputs[1] : inputs[1];

  return new Date().getFullYear() + '/' + month + '/' + date;
}

console.log(getFullDate('5/2')); //output: '2019/05/02'
```

Note:
`new Date().getFullYear()` will give you the current year.

Comment: I have edited the code. thank you so much but it still doesn't work. there aren't any errors :/